# How to insert a block into a CMS page?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, blocks, cms

I want to use [Displaze Protoshow slideshow](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/displaze-protoshow-slideshow-4874.html) on my home CMS page. The following code is suggested by Displaze to insert the slideshow in a CMS page:

```
{{block type="myslideshow/slideshow" template="displaze/myslideshow/slideshow.phtml"}}
```

If I use this code, I get the following error when the home page is loaded:

```
 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Filename cannot be empty  in /var/www/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php
```

So I tried to use

```
{{block type="Displaze_MySlideshow_Block_Slideshow" setTemplate="displaze/myslideshow/slideshow.phtml"}}
```

The error is gone, but the block is still not rendered.

On request the block code:

```
class Displaze_MySlideshow_Block_Slideshow extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

/* Some function */
}
```

The extension `etc/config.xml` code:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Displaze_MySlideshow>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </Displaze_MySlideshow>
</modules>


<global>

    <helpers>
        <myslideshow>
            <class>Displaze_MySlideshow_Helper</class>
        </myslideshow>
    </helpers>

    <!-- Global Blocks definition -->
    <blocks>
        <myslideshow>
            <class>Displaze_MySlideshow_Block</class>
        </myslideshow>
    </blocks>
   ...
```

Comment: the first option is the standard way, could you please post your block and config.xml so we can see if there is an issue with those.

Comment: check if the extension is compatible with your magento version. also see if all the files are properly placed in their location.

Comment: @DavidManners done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template files were located on `app/design/frontend/default/default/template` instead of `app/design/frontend/base/default/template`.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when the template that is specified under `template` does not exist. Please double check that this template is there and that it can be found in you theme set-up.

To double check. I am running 1.7.0.2 and have downloaded this extension and this extension does not happen with the default set-up.